# Play sound from Jenkins script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, raspberry-pi, jenkins

I run Jenkins on Ubuntu Mate on a Raspberry Pi 2 which has sound hardware (via HDMI).

When connected via SSH, sounds works great.

However, it does not work via Jenkins. I tried an `espeak 'hi'`, the build succeedes, but it does not actually produce any sound at all in the speakers.

I assume the current behavior is the default Jenkins behavior, but I would like to be able to play audio files during the build (every hour).

How can I do that?

---

Output of the pulse processes:

```
# WORKING :: When connected via SSH
jenkins   1461  0.5  1.1 144876  9652 ?        Ssl  17:53   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
lightdm   1477  0.7  1.2 155872 11348 ?        S<sl 17:53   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
ionicab+  1596  1.2  1.3 155984 11572 ?        Ssl  17:54   0:01 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal

# NOT WORKING :: When running from Jenkins and not connected via SSH
jenkins   1461  0.1  0.6 144876  5824 ?        Ssl  17:53   0:01 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
lightdm   1477  0.2  0.8 155872  7092 ?        S<sl 17:53   0:01 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal

# WORKING :: When running from Jenkins and connected via SSH
jenkins   1461  0.1  0.6 144876  5568 ?        Ssl  17:53   0:01 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
lightdm   1477  0.1  0.7 155872  6852 ?        S<sl 17:53   0:01 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
ionicab+  2271 12.5  1.2 156108 11124 ?        Ssl  18:05   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
jenkins   2345  0.0  0.0   9636   492 ?        S    18:05   0:00 grep pulse
```

Comment: Possibly you need Pulse Audio running for the user Jenkins runs as.

Comment: Well... but why does it work when connected via SSH? It works even from the Jenkins script when I keep an SSH session started.

Comment: See `ps aux | grep pulse` and compare with the user you play the script with.

Comment: @tom463 Added the output.

Comment: The only relevant entry is `ionicab+`, whatever that is. Who are the scripts run as? Who are you logging in as through SSH?

Comment: @tom463 Oh, I am authenticated as `ionicab+` (that is me). The scripts are run from the jenkins job as `jenkins` (already part of the `audio` group).

Comment: Have you checked syslog and userlog?

Comment: @tom463 What should I search for there?

Comment: Errors, warnings.

Comment: Did you restart Jenkins server after adding to the audio group?